# When to use "of"? "noun1 noun2" vs. "noun2 of the noun1"

Tags: nouns

When I want to compound two nouns, I often don't know whether I should simply concatenate the nouns, or use *of*. For example:

- *measurement location* vs. *location of the measurement*
- *figure source* vs. *source of the figure*

Is there any rule to decide which option is correct? When both options are correct, how to decide which option is the best choice?

Comment: I'll be very interested to know this. I know something about whether to use apostrophe or *of* but this is noun noun or *of* +1 :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preposition *of* can signify a relationship between two nouns, but it's not always a spatio-temporal relationship - more commonly, it indicates some kind of ownership.

Semantically, there is no difference between the noun phrases *measurement location* and *location of the measurement*.

However, *figure source* is an odd turn of phrase, and I would expect *source of the figure* to be transformed into *the figure's source* instead.

You could, equally, for the first phrase, say *the measurement's location*, but there's something about *figure source* that seems infelicitous - perhaps someone else can expound on this further.

However, **in answer to your question**, I would decide whether it is the *location*, or the *measurement* that is the new information in my text. For example:

> The measurement occurred at 11.59pm, and provided no additional information. While a number of other factors may have altered its outcome, the *location of the measurement* was not relevant.

This is more a stylistic choice, but is related to the idea of Given vs New information in a text, where typically we place the Given information toward the beginning of a clause, *except* where New information is being highlighted. It's a tricky subject - [SIL](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/glossaryoflinguisticterms/WhatIsGivenVersusNewInformatio.htm) has a brief description of it - but essentially it's a choice that affects the information flow in a discourse.

Incidentally, I'd only use *the measurement's location*, and not *measurement location* in the text above, since we're referring to a specific instance. If it were speaking about general cases, *measurement location* might be apt, for instance:

> 1. Ensure that the temperature probe is fully submerged at an appropriate location. The *measurement location* should be no less than 2cm away from the edge of the body.

Other factors to consider might be which noun the emphasis is on - in the above examples, whether it's the *location* or the *measurement*. This is a side-effect of, and secondary to, Given-New decisions.